# add external jar to Spring boot maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have two spring boot projects

1. first project contain my Entity, DTO and REPO class
2. Second is containing all Controller and service

so here what we trying to do i am creating jar of my entity project as add as mavan dependency into second project after adding dependency in Pom file of 2nd project i also add jar in .m2 or with 1st project directory

After adding mavan dependency 1st project in pom am not getting any error but when i am trying to access any class or my 1st project am not able to find in class

***2nd Project pom file***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.coreservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>bms-coreservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bms-coreservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bms</groupId>
            <artifactId>dataload</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <!--    <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/dataload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.munerf.modelmapper-spring-boot-starter/modelmapper-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.munerf.modelmapper-spring-boot-starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***After adding Dependency  mavan repo list  showing jar***

[image]

**I also try that**

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>In Project Repo</name>
            <url>file://${basedir}\src\lib\dataload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: Did you use maven build for your 2nd project? Is there any error message?

Comment: no am not getting error

Comment: dependencies with a system-path aren't included in the archive. Why don't you just declare a dependency without a system path? Your jar of the first project should be published in a shared repository.

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly you can put this code into pom file which project do you want to inject to another
>
> `For example this is DAO ' s pom file`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tr.com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project-dao</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <application.module.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</application.module.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

> And you can access into another project to this DAO 
>   You must put this code another project' pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tr.com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project.dao</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install the project of the external JAR using maven:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

or if the jar was built using maven then this already would be enough:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

This project then will simply be available in your maven repository and you can include it as you do with any other maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: First add all jar files in lib folder in the root directory of the project.

## Plugin to include all jar files in one .war

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <warName>ROOT</warName>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            <includes>
              <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

- This configuration tells Maven to include all jar files in the lib directory, and place them in the WEB-INF/lib directory in the war file. When you run mvn clean install, Maven will package the jar files with your war file.

## Plugin to include all jars in one jar

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <warName>ROOT</warName>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            <includes>
              <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

- This configuration tells Maven to include the dependency.jar file in the lib directory in the jar file, and to specify the classpath in the jar's manifest. The jar file will be built in the target directory, and you can run the jar file with the command java -jar target/your-jar-file.jar.
- Try building the project from Eclipse or any other IDEs.

> Right click Project > Run as > maven build... > mvn clean install